# Importing key pair to existing key pair file

Tags: java, ssl, keytool, self-signed

I have two different key pair values which generated using **Java keytool** and stored in two different files called keystore1.jks and keystore2.jks.

What I did is I have imported the key pair from **keystore2.jks to keystore1.jks** by the below command

```
keytool -importkeystore -srcstoretype JKS -srckeystore <source_keystorfile> -deststoretype JKS -destkeystore <keystorfile_to_import_keypair>
```

I have added the **keystore1.jks** to server to listen in ssl using this keystore.

Now I have import the public key from the file keystore2.jks to truststore file named truststore.jks

From this truststore.jks file when I try to connect to the server which is listen in ssl using keystore1.jks, server unfortunately not accepting the connection and throwing an exception as below

```
    javax.jms.JMSException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:62)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1298)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1382)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:309)
    at com.sample.ssl.job.handler.MessageQueueLocator.getJmsSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.sample.ssl.job.handler.MessageQueueLocator.sendMessageToGeneralQueue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sample.ssl.communication.JobResposeDispatcherInvoker.dispatchStartupMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sample.ssl.job.MessageDispatchJob.dispatchStartupMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sample.ssl.job.MessageDispatchJob.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1731)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1206)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:925)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1170)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:637)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:89)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedOutputStream.flush(TcpBufferedOutputStream.java:115)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:106)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.oneway(TcpTransport.java:181)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.oneway(InactivityMonitor.java:255)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.sendWireFormat(WireFormatNegotiator.java:168)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.sendWireFormat(WireFormatNegotiator.java:84)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.start(WireFormatNegotiator.java:74)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport.doReconnect(FailoverTransport.java:844)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport$2.iterate(FailoverTransport.java:135)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:122)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:289)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:263)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:184)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1185)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:139)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.doValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:330)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:178)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:250)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:275)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:421)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifySignature(BasicChecker.java:133)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:112)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:117)
    ... 32 more
```

I don't know in which I have made a mistake. In my case **half** portion of clients use trust store of the key pair from **keystore1.jks** and **remaining** use **keystore2.jks**.

The **clients** those use trust store of **keystore1.jks connecting** to the server **fine**. But those **clients** use trust store of **keystore2.jks is unable to connect**.

Please help me in this context to resolve. If I have made anything wrong in my way please give a correct path. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `keytool -list -keystore keystore1.jks` on the server to make sure that both keys are in the key store.

Comment: Does the server accept self-signed certificates? The server may not be trusting the certificate that is in the Keystore2.jks.

Comment: @mhawke I have check with the command which you mentioned and the both keys are exists in the key file

Comment: @always_a_rookie_to_learn Ya the server will accept self signed certificates. When I try with a single key then my setup is working fine. When I try with multiple keys only the problem comes.

Comment: @BhuvaneshWaran Is your server configured to accept only the certificates from your truststore 1? Did you provide alias of the certificate or any specific information in your SSL settings of your server?

Comment: @always_a_rookie_to_learn I have used only one truststore in that I have imported public keys from both keystore 1 & 2. I have differentiated the alias of both, for public key from keystore 1 I have given alias as serverkey1 and serverkey2 for the public key of keystore 2.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand some things from you..
You have two files that have passwords..  You import the second file to the first.
So. why do you need to use a second file?

I think the command should be: (backup first)
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore2.jks -deskeystore keystore1.jks

Comment: I have not use the second file i.e keystore2.jks in server anymore as I have imported the key to keystore1.jks. I have imported the public key to the file named truststore.jks and have used this file in client to connect with server.